# Come mai si usa l'espressione "e/o" e non solamente "o"?

Tags: word-usage, mathematics

Salve a tutti, stasera sono uscito a cena con degli amici ed è saltato fuori un discorso che trovo interessante. La questione riguardava l'usanza dell'espressione "e/o", che secondo me è "ripetitiva", perché credo si possa usare solamente la congiunzione "o".

Per esempio la domanda

> "Ti piacerebbe andare a mangiare una pizza e/o andare al cinema?"

Secondo me ha lo stesso senso logico della domanda:

> "Ti piacerebbe andare a mangiare una pizza o andare al cinema?"

Io sostengo che le due frasi abbiano lo stesso senso, siccome la "tabella della verità" della congiunzione "o" è la seguente:

| A | B | A ∨ B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| F | F | **F** |
| F | V | **V** |
| V | F | **V** |
| V | V | **V** |

e la tabella della verità della congiunzione "e" è la seguente:

| A | B | A ∧ B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| F | F | **F** |
| F | V | **F** |
| V | F | **F** |
| V | V | **V** |

In ognuno dei quattro possibili casi: "niente pizza, né cinema; pizza, ma niente cinema; cinema, ma niente pizza, sia cinema che pizza" la risposta alle due domande sarebbe la stessa, ovvero rispettivamente: "no; sì; sì, sì".

Ora, mi sembra chiaro che la congiunzione "e/o" si usi per aiutare la comprensibilità di un discorso ed evitare di dover ragionare ad uno stato puramente logico, ma mi chiedevo se nella lingua italiana, la congiunzione "o" avesse la stessa funzione della tabella mostrata sopra, oppure se avesse più un significato di "o uno o l'altro".

P.S.: mi ritorna in mente la seguente barzelletta:

> Un logico è appena diventato padre ed un amico gli chiede: "è maschio o feminna?" "Sì!".

Comment: Benvenuto su Italian.SE!

Comment: @Charo Grazie mille!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ovviamente hai ragione tu, e chiunque sappia un minimo di logica.

L'unico vago argomento a favore dell'inutile “e/o” è che mentre in latino esistevano due congiunzioni distinte *vel* (che indicava una disgiunzione inclusiva come appunto l'OR logico) e *aut* (che indicava una disgiunzione esclusiva, come in logica lo XOR), in italiano la congiunzione “o” [ha entrambi i possibili significati](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/o1/) (oltre ad altri), e quindi a volte qualcuno sente il bisogno di sottolineare l'inclusività in quel modo (anche se spesso risulta inutile perché in molti casi l'“o” esclusivo non avrebbe senso).